# How to set alpha parameter for background in gganimate

Tags: r, gganimate

I try to set alpha parameter 0.1 for background in my animation:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

mtcars_ <- rename(mtcars, mpg_ = mpg, disp_ = disp)
mtcars_$mpg = min(mtcars$mpg)
gg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_density_2d_filled(data = mtcars_, aes(x = mpg_, y = disp_), alpha = 0.1) + geom_line() + theme(legend.position = "none")
gg
anim <- gg + transition_reveal(mpg) + shadow_wake(1)
anim
```

but alpha is 1 in final movie. How to fix it?

I need movie with this image
[image]

Comment: You want the background of the panel to be transparent? Because your code assigns the transparency to the geom_density_2d_filled() geoms.

Comment: Yes, I want transparent background as on my `gg` plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to replicate the data you need for each frame. geom_density should see everything in every frame, but geom_line should only "see" the values up to the currently displayed value. We could accomplish that using `tidyr::uncount` to make copies of our data, and then creating a variable for `geom_line` that is NA when the value is too high for the current frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

distinct_mpg <- mtcars %>% distinct(mpg) %>% arrange(mpg) %>% pull(mpg)
  
mtcars_frames <- mtcars %>%
  uncount(length(distinct_mpg), .id = "frame") %>%
  mutate(mpg_reveal = distinct_mpg[frame],
         mpg_shown = if_else(mpg <= mpg_reveal, mpg, NA_real_)) 

animate(
  ggplot(mtcars_frames, aes(y = disp)) +
    geom_density_2d_filled(aes(x = mpg), alpha = 0.1) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = mpg_shown, group = frame)) +
    transition_states(frame) +
    scale_fill_viridis_d(guide = NULL),
  fps = 20
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might just want either to remove the `shadow_wake()` or set its wake_length closer to 0. The visual results will be similar, but the computation time will be higher for the shadow_wake() option.

```
gg1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_density_2d_filled(data = mtcars_, aes(x = mpg_, y = disp_), alpha = 0.2) + geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank())

gg1 + transition_reveal(mpg)
```

## shadow_wake() removed

[image]

Or set shadow_wake to a lower setting.

```
gg2 <- 
  ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_density_2d_filled(data = mtcars_ , aes(x = mpg_, y = disp_), alpha = 0.2) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.background = element_blank())

 gg2 + transition_reveal(mpg) + shadow_wake(wake_length = 0.05)
```

## shadow_wake() lowered

[image]

Comment: It does not work. Your background alpha is 1. I need 0.1

Comment: Help me understand one thing. The panel border is plotted before (or "below") the geoms.  Thus it can not hide or cover any of the geoms. Why would you need to make it transparent for? Is it to place this figure on top of another one?

Comment: I have updated my question and uploaded desired background